# ORA-01797: this operator must be followed by ANY or ALL error

Tags: sql, oracle

While I am executing the query,

```
select *
from file_log f
where F.DCP_SRCE_FILENM_FK in ('ABC','DEF') and
      F.TRANS_DT>=to_date('08/25/2017','mm/dd/yyyy') and
      F.TRANS_DT<=('08/30/2017','mm/dd/yyyy')
```

am getting the following error:

> ORA-01797: this operator must be followed by ANY or ALL.

Could you all please help me in writing the proper query so that this error would go?

Answer (score 3):

Just use the `date` keyword and ISO constants:

```
select *
from file_log f
where F.DCP_SRCE_FILENM_FK in ('ABC','DEF') and
      F.TRANS_DT >= date '2017-08-25' and
      F.TRANS_DT <= date '2017-08-30';
```

You are getting the error because the second constant is missing `to_date()`.  But you might as well use the proper syntax for a date constant.

Comment: to_date is a perfectly good way of specifying a date literal too, as per [the documentation]:(https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51062) `DATE literals are the only case in which Oracle Database accepts a TO_DATE expression in place of a string literal.`

Answer (score 3):

You are missing `TO_DATE`:

```
select *
from file_log f
where F.DCP_SRCE_FILENM_FK in ('ABC','DEF') and
      F.TRANS_DT>=to_date('08/25/2017','mm/dd/yyyy') and
      F.TRANS_DT<=TO_DATE('08/30/2017','mm/dd/yyyy')     -- Missing on this line
```

**Why it is throwing that exception**:

The SQL parser cannot discern that you intended to use a `TO_DATE` function and assumes the final line is trying to compare `F.TRANS_DT` with one (`ANY`) or both (`ALL`) the values `('08/30/2017','mm/dd/yyyy')` so is assuming the query should have the syntax:

```
select *
from file_log f
where F.DCP_SRCE_FILENM_FK in ('ABC','DEF') and
      F.TRANS_DT>=to_date('08/25/2017','mm/dd/yyyy') and
      F.TRANS_DT<= ANY ('08/30/2017','mm/dd/yyyy')
```

Which is a syntactically valid query. It would not, however, execute as trying to parse the `F.TRANS_DT <= 'mm/dd/yyyy'` comparison will result in trying to implicitly convert the string on the right-hand side to a date which is almost certain to fail with `ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected`. But the SQL parser has done its best to suggest what is missing to make the query valid.

Answer (score 0):

For those who end up searching for `ORA-01797` error:

This error appears when right side of a logical operator ( =, !=, >, <, <=, >= ) contains multiple values.

Possible solutions:

1. Make sure right hand side of the logical operator contains a single value.
2. Handle multiple values by using `IN` instead of ( = ) and  `NOT IN` instead of ( != )
3. Handle multiple values by using `ALL`, `ANY` or `SOME` as [documented](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/all-any-some-comparison-conditions-in-sql).